Australian(?) movie/TV film? - a prince dressed in gold meets a high school kid for an adventure
This is a movie/TV film I've been trying to find for a very long time. I have searched the internet, Google images, IMDb and I have been very unfortunate. 
I remember the following: 

Possibly in the 90's
Australian and/or New Zealand accents
Starts with a high school brat being waken up by his mum 
He meets a prince dressed in gold/made up in gold - the prince does all kinds of tricks and impresses the high school brat. I specifically remember a scene in a basketball court at a school.
The prince was shorter and maybe he was of Indian/Pakistani origin.
The high school kid is taller and white.
The prince seems to come from a castle up in the clouds
The story is about saving the castle or some candle which if it lights out , they lose their magic powers
Towards the end of the movie I remember a pram with the brat dressed as a baby (a spell was cast on him) going through a forest full of green evil(?) people. I remember they took a jump from a cliff in the forest to reach the magic castle to save it from the evil woman. They kept saying this magic word 'khoo khoo khooo' to get to the castle as if they needed the energy/power for the pram to fly high enough to get there.
I remember the prince waking up in the castle being served cereal that were different colours
There was an evil woman at the castle up in the skies that was threatening/putting in danger the prince's parents.

That's all I can probably remember.

You might want to give the question a more descriptive title - so it attracts attention more on the front page.

Good question. I'm fairly certain someone was looking for this movie before, but can't find the old Q. :(

no one seems to know it I guess :(

I'm looking for that movie too!!!!! I nowremember the kid becoming a baby! forgot that part.
Here's all I remembered: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65724/a-prince-kid-comes-to-our-world-and-fulfills-wishes-for-a-kid-until-sunset-to-sa
Someone wrote on mine that it's a duplicate, and thank god he did! Now I know im not the only one who saw this movie! It was aired years ago on tv, and I just started wathicng it and liked it a lot, but never saw it again. It's only in my memory now. Find it's name!!

found it!!!!!!!!!! Googled "Wishes australian film", thanks to the other poster who used the word tv-film, seems that movie was not enough for google (:
I want to thank the world!!!!!!!! The movie name is "More Winners: The Big Wish (1990)" you can see it here: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100187/
Thanks to everyone who helped!!!!! it really helped to me that you've said it was australian and that it was more a film. really helped!!!! Thank you so much for providing this detail!!!!!! Happy hanukkah from Israel! חג אורים שמח!

Yinon this is the one!!!! Oh my good! I've been looking to find the movie for years and years.

Me too,  I think I saw it when I was 8 or 12. It's been like 10 years but I've never forgot that movie 'cause it was too good! feels great to know it now, knowing it's not more an anonymous movie in my head. next step is watching it, after watching the 3 clips and trailer which is all I've found (:
without you being sure it was australian and calling it a "film", I wouldn't have found it. who knows for how long. it's funny that both you and me have decided to ask about it now, same year same month. I've always looked for it myself but last night I felt like lets find this movie already!

How long did you look for it? when did you watch it?

I've been trying for a while now. Maybe 2-3 years. I think I added one more post here a long time ago but it never got so much attention. I think I watched it when I was 13-15 years old? So nearly 14-16 years ago. I know, it's funny that you created the thread this month too. I read your thread too but I didn't remember any of what you said! I also watched the 3 video clips on youtube today. I'm not sure how I can find the movie to watch it all once again.

Look for the dvd, you may buy it somewhere,  I plan to, and then upload it so this movie would be available to everyone who tried to get it!
You also mentioned things I've forgot or didnt remember. I thought the prince looked more like Draco Malfoy from Harry Potter, maybe cause yellow and blond and I think drack is wearing a weird suit too, maybe in the second movie.

If you manage to buy it before me, send me the movie! :D

and just to be sure, here's my mail: yinonzadok@gmail.com
