Rare movie about a prince kid that comes to our world and fulfills wishes for a kid until sunset to save his world from a man causing a green smoke
the bad man in the magical world causes a green smoke to spread there and it starts to kill residents in the kingdom.
The king and the queen sends their child to our world, where he needs to fulfill wishes for someone, 'cause this somehow will save their kingdom.
The kid prince arrives in the middle of a basketball game, sitting on the basket ring, and the kids are asking him questiones. he tells them what he came for but they dont believe him, except for one kid who decides to check it.
after the prince proves it to him, they walk and the human kid sees a girl he likes and wishes to become her best friend, the prince tells him it's done and he goes to her and says hi, but after her referring to him as a girl he moves his head to the store's window and looks on his reflection, discovering the prince turned him into a girl (:
another wish is to become popular and he becomes a movies-star with lots of money.
By midafternoon the prince power becomes weaker, and the prince becomes weak too. they hurry to the prince's world before the sun sets, and when they reach a cliff the prince is really weak and needs help. They gets into a shopping cart and the prince makes it fly with his finger, the human kid is holding his finger high and saying "Fly" or other word together with the prince, but the prince is too weak now and the sun is setting, they probably won't make it.

Possible duplicate here.

Yes! this is the movie!! someone find it's name pls!

walt, pls try to find the other old thread. the answer might be there! I don't want to forget this movie!

If someone needs more details, click on the duplicate link above, or on this link http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64907/australian-movie-tv-film-a-prince-dressed-in-gold-meets-a-high-school-kid#comment104876_64907

found it!!!!!!!!!! Googled "Wishes australian film", thanks to the other poster who used the word tv-film, seems that movie was not enough for google (: I want to thank the world!!!!!!!! The movie name is "More Winners: The Big Wish (1990)" you can see it here: imdb.com/title/tt0100187 Thanks to everyone who helped!!!!! it really helped to me that you've said it was australian and that it was more a film. really helped!!!! Thank you so much for providing this detail!!!!!! Happy hanukkah from Israel! חג אורים שמח!

Glad you found it. Feel free to put up the answer (preferably with some details, like a synopsis and a clip) and also answer the other Q, if you want.

This is More Winners: The Big Wish (1990) from Australia.

Prince Wilton travels to Earth via 'vortex', to dispose of seven wishes which, if not granted by sundown, will result upon the faeries losing their magic forever. Thereupon he meets Walter Pratt who is attending his first day at a new school.

Here's the trailer:



Here you can watch 3 clips from the movie: http://aso.gov.au/titles/tv/big-wish/clip1/
